# Django: retrieving values of ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I am attempting to implement a 'download csv' action in the django admin, to download the data associated with any model. To handle all models together, and to prevent the need for code changes if the model is changed, I am trying to implement one function (`download_csv`) that programmatically gets the fields associated with the model, and then saves a row for each object with the values of each field filled in.

However, ManyToMany relationships result in an error such as:
`ManyToManyRel' object has no attribute 'value_from_object`.

How can I retrieve the values of these fields? 
The function works when downloading Lectures, but not Speakers, since the ManyToMany relationship is "reversed" (i.e. contained in the model `Lecture`).

models.py

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Lecture(models.Model):
    lecture_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    speaker = models.ManyToManyField(Speaker)
```

admin.py

```
def download_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    '''
    Download CSV of all objects in queryset
    '''

    try:
        main_model = modeladmin.corresponding_model
    except AttributeError:
        modeladmin.message_user(request, 'That action cannot be performed on these objects.')
        return

    fields = main_model._meta.get_fields()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.csv'

    writer = csv.writer(response, csv.excel)
    writer.writerow(fields)

    for obj in queryset:
        writer.writerow([field.value_from_object(obj) for field in fields])

    return response

admin.site.register(Speaker, SpeakerAdmin)
admin.site.add_action(download_csv, 'export_csv')
```

Comment: try:[field.field.value_from_object(obj) if instanceof(field, ForeignObjectRel) else field.value_from_object(obj) for field in fields]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I used `isinstance` rather than `instanceof`. However, I now get an `AttributeError: 'Speaker' object has no attribute 'speaker'`. It's likely this is the right direction, but I don't understand the internals of ManyToMany fields enough.

Comment: Got it. Replacing the second `field` in your answer @Blackdoor with `target_field` (i.e. `[field.target_field.value_from_object(obj) if isinstance(field, ForeignObjectRel) else field.value_from_object(obj) for field in fields]`) gives the desired result (the id of the lecture corresponding to the given speaker). I will experiment further to get (e.g.) the lecture_title as well. Many thanks!